# React-typescript-Redux-toolkit: failed to fetch nested api

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, redux-toolkit

I am practicing redux-toolkit with typescript. I have use one [open api](https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character%60) and for fetching data I used redux toolkit's `createAsyncThunk`. I successfully able to fetched the data in app's component. When I console log it, I can able to see the data but as soon I map the `data.result` I am getting error: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined`. I think I have made Typescript error when I used the interface. But don't see where is the problem and Also in Chrome's reduxdevtools: `data` expect object but I put arrays. This my [redux-devtools looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hUmRo.png).
I shared my code in [Codesand Box](https://codesandbox.io/s/hopeful-star-03nq6).

`PS: I am sharing only these two files below because I think this is where I making mistakes`

**This is my Reducer, I think I making mistake in types**

```
import { createSlice, createAsyncThunk } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

export const dataFetch = createAsyncThunk(
  `store/dataFetch`,
  async () => {
    const url = `https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character`;
    const response = await fetch(url);
    const data = await response.json();
    return data;
  }
);

interface Meta {
  loading: boolean;
  error: boolean;
  message: string;
}
// This is where I am making mistake
interface Results {
  name: string;
  image: string;
  gender: string;
  species: string;
  status: string;
}

interface Info {
  count: number;
  pages: number;
}

interface User {
  results: Results[];
  info: Info;

}

export interface IUser {
  meta: Meta;
  data: User[];
}

const initialState: IUser = {
  "meta": {
    "loading": false,
    "error": false,
    "message": ``
  },
  "data": []
};

const UserSlice = createSlice({
  "name": `JsonPlacehoder user`,
  initialState,
  "reducers": {

  },
  "extraReducers": (builder) => {
    builder.addCase(dataFetch.pending, (state) => (
      {
        ...state,
        "meta": {
          ...state.meta,
          "loading": true
        }
      }
    ));
    builder.addCase(dataFetch.fulfilled, (state, { payload }) => (
      {
        ...state,
        "meta": {
          ...state.meta,
          "loading": false,
          "error": false,
          "message": ``
        },
        "data": payload
      }
    ));
    builder.addCase(dataFetch.rejected, (state, { error }) => {
      window.alert(error?.message);
      return {
        ...state,
        "meta": {
          "loading": false,
          "error": true,
          "message": error?.message || ``
        }
      };
    });
  }
});

export default UserSlice.reducer;
```

**This is my component where I am getting error when I using map function**

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';

import { useSelector, useDispatch } from 'react-redux'

import { dataFetch } from './store/reducers';
import { IRootState } from './store/combineReducers';

function App() {

  const { data, meta } = useSelector((rootState: IRootState) => rootState.fetchUser);

  console.log(data);

  const dispatch = useDispatch()


  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(dataFetch())
  }, [dispatch])

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {
        data.results.map(i => { //GETTING ERROR
          return <div>
            <h1>{i.name}</h1>
          </div>
        })
      }
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because you are trying to `.map` over the data before the fetch has even started.

Your `useEffect` triggers after the first render. Before that, you already tried to `.map` once.
And even then, during loading, your component might rerender.

That in combination that some of your reducers tend to actually remove the `data` attribute instead of keeping `data: []` (I'm looking at pending there) lead to `data` being undefined on some renders.

A `TypeError` is actually not a TypeScript error (these always begin with "ts" followed by a number), but a JavaScript runtime error. So you really have a "runtime crash" here.

Comment: optional chaining is the solution `data?.results?.map`